# Node.JS Function Fails Every Other Time

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

My node.js launch function fails every other time - without fail. It's hosted in AWS Lambda for use in an Alexa skill. When it works, Alexa speaks the result of my query perfectly. The other half of the time, she says an error has been encountered.

Here's what I'm working with. This is only my second project with node.js, so sample code is much appreciated.

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var pool = mysql.createConnection({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host     : 'my host',
  user     : 'test',
  password : 'test',
  database: 'test',
});


const handlers = {

   'LaunchRequest': function () {

pool.query('SELECT versetext, book, reference  FROM myverses ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1', 
function (error, results, fields) {
   // handle if error or no result...
   console.log(JSON.stringify(results[0].versetext));
   var scripture = JSON.stringify(results[0].versetext).replace(/['"]+/g, '');
   var book = JSON.stringify(results[0].book).replace(/['"]+/g, '');
   var reference = JSON.stringify(results[0].reference).replace(/['"]+/g, '');
   this.emit(':tell', scripture + " " + "<say-as interpret-as='ordinal'>" + book + "</say-as>" + " " + reference);

 }.bind(this));

pool.end();

    },


    'AMAZON.HelpIntent': function () {
        const speechOutput = this.t('HELP_MESSAGE');
        const reprompt = this.t('HELP_MESSAGE');
        this.emit(':ask', speechOutput, reprompt);
    },
    'AMAZON.CancelIntent': function () {
        this.emit(':tell', this.t('STOP_MESSAGE'));
    },
    'AMAZON.StopIntent': function () {
        this.emit(':tell', this.t('STOP_MESSAGE'));
    },

      'Unhandled': function () {
        this.emit(':tell', "Sorry, pal.");

    },

};

exports.handler = function (event, context) {
    const alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
    alexa.appId = APP_ID;
    // To enable string internationalization (i18n) features, set a resources object.
    alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
    alexa.execute();
};
```

And here is the error log I get every other time. It seems to be flagging my use of `results[0]`, but I'm not sure why.

```
   {
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: 679ead1f-0d5a-11e8-a5b3-fd55e0ced610 Process exited before completing request"
}

Request ID:
"679ead1f-0d5a-11e8-a5b3-fd55e0ced610"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: 679ead1f-0d5a-11e8-a5b3-fd55e0ced610 Version: $LATEST
2018-02-09T05:30:57.207Z    679ead1f-0d5a-11e8-a5b3-fd55e0ced610    TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:35:38)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:88:24)
    at /var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:225:14
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
END RequestId: 679ead1f-0d5a-11e8-a5b3-fd55e0ced610
REPORT RequestId: 679ead1f-0d5a-11e8-a5b3-fd55e0ced610  Duration: 83.15 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 45 MB  
RequestId: 679ead1f-0d5a-11e8-a5b3-fd55e0ced610 Process exited before completing request
```

Comment: see that line `function(error, results, fields) {` ... how about checking if there's an `error` before blindly assuming `results` is OK (which it won't be if there's an error) - knowing the actual error returned by the query will be far more useful to you than worrying about an exception caused by not handling errors appropriately

Comment: @JaromandaX Here's the error: `Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit.` This seems strange, since I'm terminating the connection AFTER the query.

Comment: at least you have a better idea of what the problem is now

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was as simple as removing the `pool.end();` line altogether.